# waitpid call in C

Tags: c

I have created a simple program to verify use of statloc parameter in waitpid() call by demonstrating child and parent process. I have read somewhere that return value through exit() in any process goes to parent via statloc . Thus I am trying to print statloc variable in parent context but it is appearing different from what I am returning through exit(). Please correct me if I have misunderstood. Below is the code and result : ( I am expecting 234 as statloc value )

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int main ()

{
pid_t pid;
char ch;
int statloc;



if((pid=fork())!=0)
{

 /* parents code */
printf( "\n pid of child process is %d ", pid);

printf("\nI am in parent  ");

waitpid(-1,&statloc,0);

printf("\n I have yet not exited from parent ");
printf( "\n value of statloc is %d ",statloc ) ; // expecting 234 as statloc's value

exit(0);
}

if(pid==0)
{

printf("\n hello, in child's code \n");

printf("\n Exiting child's code \n ");
exit(234);

}    

}
```

> Output

:

```
avotclbh:/home/akhils/prep#./a.out

 hello, in child's code

 Exiting child's code
 pid of child process is 12464
 I am in parent
 I have yet not exited from parent
 value of statloc is 59904
```

Comment: Read e.g. [this `waitpid` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html). It will tell you that the value you get is a set of *flags* bitwised ored together, plus the actual return value from the process.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `C++` if you are asking about `C`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`WEXITSTATUS(statloc)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) to get child process exit code.